# How to fill an array of object pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to complete a homework assignment to create a Shape class hierarchy. In main(), I am trying to fill an array of pointers to the Shape objects. Then, after filling I need to loop through that array and call the print() (here called "SendToString") function on each object pointer.

When running this it crashes on the 2nd for loop at runtime right after I enter some shapes and then enter 'done'. It can't seem to loop through the shape_array?

In getShape(), if the user types 'done' in the console, a NULL pointer is returned. When a NULL pointer is returned from getShape(), the loop in main() should exit and stop filling the array.

What is wrong with my code? I have combed through for hours and cannot see the problem. Thanks.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Shape.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Shape* getShape();

int main()
{

    int i; //fill the shape array.
    int j; //loop through the shape array.
    string output;

    Shape* shape_array[15]; //array of base Shape pointers
    Shape *shape_ptr;

    int nElements = sizeof(shape_array) / sizeof(shape_array[0]);

    cout << "Enter a list of shapes - 'done' to end" << endl;

    //fill the array of shape object pointers
    for (i =0; i <= nElements; i++) { //loop through the defined array of 15 elements

        shape_ptr = getShape(); //return a shape ptr or NULL ptr
        if (shape_ptr== NULL) 
        {
            break; //stop filling the array (stop calling getShape)
        }
        else
        {
            shape_array[i]= shape_ptr; //add the shape pointer

        }

    } //end for
    cout << "The list of shapes entered..." << endl;

    for (j = 0; j < nElements; j++) {

        output = shape_array[j]->SendToString();
        cout << output << endl;
    } 

    return 0;

} //end main
```

And here is the Output:

```
Enter a list of shapes - 'done' to end

Enter the shape's color (or 'done')...
green
Enter shape type...
circle
Enter the radius...
5.0
Enter the shape's color (or 'done')...
red
Enter shape type...
circle
Enter the radius...
4.0
Enter the shape's color (or 'done')...
done
User entered done!
The list of shapes entered...
green circle with a radius of 5 and area of 78
```

It cannot print the second object and crashes there.

Comment: You're accessing the array out of bounds. Look at this loop: `for (i =0; i <= nElements; i++)`.

Comment: If `getShape` returns dynamically allocated `Shape`s, you're probably leaking them. If it doesn't you probably have dangling pointers.

Comment: Changed the loop bound to (i =0; i < nElements; i++). But the code is still crashing in the same place.

Comment: Well, you then go on to de-reference *all* of the elements of the array.

Comment: What do you mean by dangling pointer? The getShape() function returns an object pointer to a Shape s. For example, ps = new Circle(nColor, radius);

Comment: Ok, so you return a pointer to dynamically allocated memory. Unless one of your other functions tacks on freeing that memory, you never free it. That was the first conditional in my statement. Hence, dangling pointers doesn't apply.

Answer (score 3):

Like juanchopanza said in his comment, you are accessing the array out of bounds.

```
for (j = 0; j <= nElements; j++) {
```

Should be:

```
for (j = 0; j < nElements; j++) {
```

if I define an array of size 2 like:

```
int i[2];
```

Then I can access the first element with i[0] and the second one with i[1].  That is all 2 elements accessed, and I haven't accessed i[2].  The range of acceptable indexes in a C/C++ array is always 0 to (nElements-1).

See this:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Note also that in the last loop, you run through the whole array when you have not entered shapes for all 15 spots in the array.  These leads to you trying to access memory that is pointed to by a garbage pointer and is therefore likely to be unmapped.  This is causing the crash most likely.

Comment: yep, I caught that problem and corrected it. But I still have a problem with dereferencing the object pointers.

Comment: That is because you are looping through the whole array when only part of it is filled. You are derefferencing garbage pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the obvious out of bounds access in your first loop, you process the whole array as if all its elements pointer to valid objects:

```
for (j = 0; j < nElements; j++) {
    output = shape_array[j]->SendToString();
```

But there is no guarantee that they are, since you only set elements until the first `NULL` is returned by `getShape()`, otherwise you leave elements unset due to your strange looping technique, where you do something like this:

```
for (i =0; i < nElements; i++)
{
  shape_array[i]= something_good;
  i++;  // LOOK! Index increased one extra time per loop!!!
}
```

In your first loop, you only set every second element in the array, but you de-reference all of them. You are de-referencing invalid pointers. If you are going to be writing this kind of code, you should learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Firrst of all the valid range for indices of the array is `[0, nElements - 1]` Secondly the both loops are written incorrectly and contain bugs. For example in the first loop variable i is incremented twice.

The correct code could look the following way

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Shape.h"

Shape *getShape(); // Why this function is declared here but not is defined in the module?!

int main()
{
    const int N = 15;
    Shape* shape_array[N]; //array of base Shape pointers


    std::cout << "Enter a list of shapes - 'done' to end" << std::endl;

    //fill the array of shape object pointers
    Shape *shape_ptr;
    int nElements = 0;
    for ( ; nElements < N && ( shape_ptr = getShape() ); nElements++ ) 
    { 
        //loop through the defined array of 15 elements
        shape_array[nElements] = shape_ptr; //add the shape pointer
    } //end for

    std::cout << "The list of shapes entered..." << std::endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < nElements; i++ ) 
    {
        std::string output = shape_array[i]->SendToString();
        std::cout << output << std::endl;
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm adding the #include header file for getShape()

Comment: @astra  Why do not place the function declaration in the same header "Shape.h"?

Comment: the professor asked us to put getShape in getShape.cpp

Comment: I am getting this compiler error on nElements variable- "expression must be a modifiable value", any ideas why?

Comment: @astra Can you simply copy and paste my example, can npt you?

Comment: For some reason your line in the For loop "&& shape_ptr = getShape()" was causing the nElements to be unmodifiable. I just moved shape_ptr = getShape() to be inside the For Loop and now it compiles fine.

Comment: @astra I am sorry. There was a typo. See my updated post.